# Can I connect 2 sets of speakers to a Mackie Mix 5?

Tags: speakers, mixer

I have a Mackie Mix 5 mixer. I was going to connect the Main Outs to powered EV PA speakers. Can I connect the Tape Out to powered monitor speakers?

Comment: Yes. Not much more to say really.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Manual](https://mackie.com/sites/default/files/PRODUCT%20RESOURCES/MANUALS/Owners_Manuals/Mix5_8_12FX_OM.pdf):

> Main Out: These 1/4" TRS balanced/unbalanced outputs feed the main mix
>   out into the world. You may feed the amplifiers or powered speakers
>   this way.
>
> Tape out: Unbalanced RCA connections tap the main mix output to make
>   simultaneous recording and PA work more convenient. Connect these to
>   your laptop or standalone recorder's inputs.

Since the tape out is unbalanced i would keep the cables as short as possible.

The Mix 8 has a CR out, or control room out that would also work for this purpose..